# Combine Arrays and update a string with values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two issues I was hoping to get help on:

1. Combine two arrays into one string
   and add some formatting
2. insert the new string into a
   specific spot in a bigger string.

I have two arrays:

```
$array_1 =  array("100","200","300");
$array_2 = array("abc","def","ghi");

$result = array_merge($array_1, $array_2);

foreach ($result as $val){
//NEED HELP HERE  create a string that adds a "mac=" to the beginning of the current $val and adds a "/n" to the end of the current value.
}
```

The above should somehow create the string below:

```
 $my_string = "mac=100/n
              mac=200/n
              mac=300/n
               mac=abc/n
              mac=def/n
              mac=ghi/n";
```

Now for Part #2

I have a current string that was created already:

```
$current_String = "[MACS]/n
                   mac=blah1/n
                   mac=blah2/n
                   mac=blah3/n
                   [SERVICES]";
```

My last issue is to replace everything between `[MACS]/n` and `[SERVICES]`  with `$my_string`

So I should end up with:

```
$updated_String = "[MACS]/n
                  mac=100/n
                  mac=200/n
                  mac=300/n
                  mac=abc/n
                  mac=def/n
                  mac=ghi/n
                  [SERVICES]";
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I need a hamburger and a large coke.

Comment: Didn't mean to sound demanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$array_1 =  array("100","200","300");
$array_2 = array("abc","def","ghi");

$result = array_merge($array_1, $array_2);

$myString = "[MACS]/n\nmac=" . implode($result, "/n\nmac=") . "/n\n[SERVICES]";

//replace in other string
$macsIndex = strrpos($currentString, "[MACS]");
$servicesIndex = strrpos($currentString, "[SERVICES]");
$currentString = substr($currentString, 0, $macsIndex) . $myString . substr($currentString, servicesIndex+10);
```

Outputs:

```
[MACS]/n
mac=100/n
mac=200/n
mac=300/n
mac=abc/n
mac=def/n
mac=ghi/n
[SERVICES]
```

Comment: OK this works perfect Thanks! But what if $current_String was part of a much bigger string? Can I find and replace [MACS] and everything in between to0 [SERVICES] with $myString is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
$formatted = '';
foreach ($result as $val){
    $val = sprintf("mac=%s\n", $val);
    $formatted .= $val;
}
```